# How to turn a whole table cell into a link in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, html-table, cell

I've read a lot of questions about this problem, but none of those could solve it perfectly: the cell won't be clickable at its full height.

[image: Illustration here]

As shown in the picture, I made a headline for my webpage using the `<table>` tag and colored the clickable content into blue, while the whole table is orange.

The HTML code is:

```
<table class="visible" id="menu" align="center">
  <tr>
  <td><a href="#"><p>Home</p></a></td>
  ...
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the CSS code is:

```
#menu a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Unfortunately, as you can see, not the whole cell is blue, therefore not the whole cell is clickable. Could anyone tell me a perfect solution for this (possibly without using JavaScript)?

Comment: I tried it, but the result is the same, the height low...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `display: flex` and `justify-content: center` instead of `display: block`.

```css
a {
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" border="1">
  <tr>
  <td><a href="#"><p>Home</p></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: DONE! Thank you again :D

Comment: This only works if every cell has the same content height but if that's the case then you just need to add padding to the anchors with display block https://jsfiddle.net/1nrbL1mu/7/

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `<p/>` (block-level) inside `<a/>` (inline-level).

```
a::after {
   display:block;
   content:" "; 
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   background:yellow;
   z-index:-1;
}
td
{
   position:relative; 
   z-index:0;
}
```

delete styles for "a".

https://jsfiddle.net/1nrbL1mu/9/

This also works for IE:

```
a::after 
{
   display:block;
   content:" "; 
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   height:300px; /* max possible */
   background:yellow;
   z-index:-1;
}
td
{
   position:relative; 
   z-index:0;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1nrbL1mu/12/

Comment: This works and if you use `a:after` (one colon) it will work in IE8+ where `display: flex` won't

Comment: I use `::` for pseudoelements and `:` for pseudoclasses due to W3C recommendation. 

Tested on IE 11.

Comment: Why you want to support IE8? Can't you used upgrade to IE11? Using of old browsers is hazardous.

Comment: Unfortunately some people are still using IE8, 9 & 10 and some developers need to support it, so I was just noting that your solution can support more browsers. Newer browsers support `:` for pseudoelements so using that means it is backwards compatible.

Comment: Not true. Many users are on business managed Windows and don't have full admin rights or control to upgrade their browsers. Also Windows Vista only supports up to IE9.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152290/discussion-between-zac-and-18c).

Comment: EPIC FAIL. Block of upgrade IE on Windows... The greatest security hole. But. The IE8 in this case correctly render this solution (I tested in "F12 mode") and in this case using of one semicolon can be permitted. It is weird because IE8 not correctly handled :after and :before pseudoelements in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try puting it o new table of one column and one row

```html
<table align="center" width="175" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td> <a href="#" title="Conoce más" style="text-decoration: none; color: #010000;" target="_blank">
    
    <table align="center" width="175" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">  
<tr>    
 <td style="border: 1px solid #f3b946; text-align: center; padding: 10px 35px 10px 35px; font-size: 18px;">CONOCE&nbsp;MÁS
    </td>  
</tr>
</table>
    </a>
    
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```